# SVG vs DIV tags for a Gantt application

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom, svg

My first question on SO; so be gentle.

I am working on an application which contains a web-based Gantt application, which needs to have gantt bars for as many has 100,000 tasks, with some parent-child relationships, ability to drag and drop tasks and rearrange them, etc.

The current application has this built using HTML DIV tags. Each task/gantt-bar is a DIV with event handlers attached for handling the drag functionality. This application performs horribly when the number of tasks goes above 1000. Internal discussions led us to believe that the DOM was becoming very heavy due to the sheer number of elements that needed to be rendered when dealing with more than 1000 tasks.

Looking for options for improving performance, I came across similar applications that use SVG elements to draw the Gantt bars, which are much more performant event with larger record numbers.

Can the community help me understand why using SVG gives better results than DIV tags? To my knowledge both SVG and HTML DIV tags create separate elements for each gantt-bar in the DOM. Hence, the number of elements on the DOM, which the browser has to deal with, is the same. Why then does SVG give better performance?

Comment: not drawing stuff will give you the best results. You can't possibly display that much information and have it make sense. Design something that shows a summary and lets you pick some subset to view from that. That way you never try to display so much information and don't need so many DOM nodes.

Comment: That's a fair point for a new application. However, I am working within pre-existing constraints, and am trying to avoid having to rewrite the entire application. The application currently draws DIV tags for all the records received from the server (that can range from 100 - 100,000) and provides it within a viewport with additional data for the user to scroll down to. The issue occurs when the data-set grows large. My question though remains: Why does SVG seem to perform better than DIV tags?

Comment: SVG elements are absolutely positioned, they require no reflow to layout so they are less work for a UA to display.

Comment: Why would someone attempt to build such a complicated thing. I would look toward inexpensive yet extremely efficient applications like AnyGantt.

Comment: @KevinBrown Again, a good question. And it would be a valid consideration if one were looking to build a new application. But, as I had already stated in my question, this is an existing application which I need to deal with.

And then again, my question was more conceptual -- I wanted to understand why one was running faster than the other -- not whether the app designers had made wise choices. I am sure should that question ever be asked, it would elicit a million conflicting and subjective responses.